# Is it possible to write the constraints with the Pyomo package, but solve them using the Nsga2 meta-heuristic algorithm?

Tags: pyomo

I have a model for my master's thesis, I want to solve it through Nsga2, but I don't know how to code the limits.
I wanted to know if it is possible to write the restrictions with the Pyomo package and solve them through the Nsga2 algorithm?